# Expand & Collapse div doesn't encapsulate the HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code :

```
$(".header").click(function() {
  $('.content').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  if ($('.content').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.header span').text('Collapse');
  } else {
    $('.header span').text('Expand');
  }
});
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".header").trigger('click');
})
.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.container .header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>I'm putting a search bar here.</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
  <button>another click</button>
```

When I change HTML part to this (add a table inside the hidden `div`) :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>I'm putting a search bar here.</li>

             <table>
             <tr><td>a</td></tr>
             <tr><td>b</td></tr>
             <tr><td>c</td></tr>
             </table>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
  <button>another click</button>
```

The table looks out of the `div`, namely below the `div` and it's not hidden. How can I make that table look inside the `div`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've put a `table` inside a `ul`, that's your problem. In fact, not sure why it's even a list. Basically, the semantics of your HTML tags is all over the place.

Comment: The problem continues if I move `table` out of `ul`, it continues even if I turn list to a `p`.. Thanks for the comment btw.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle? @jason

Comment: @jason - even if you get it looking ok (you could fudge this with CSS), your HTML ain't great. Get it semantically sound first and then the style should follow.

Comment: If you say even the attempt from Vishal’s answer doesn’t work for you, then I’d suspect that you most likely have additional formatting applied to those elements that you have not shown us yet. Might be something as simple as a floated element that you forgot to properly “contain” within its parent (via the usual and researchable ways, just in case “huh?” would be your next response now.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this your expected result please have look on below snippet:

```js
$(".header").click(function() {
  $('.content').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  if ($('.content').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.header span').text('Collapse');
  } else {
    $('.header span').text('Expand');
  }
});
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".header").trigger('click');
})
```

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.container .header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <p>I'm putting a search bar here.</p>
     <table>
       <tr><td>a</td></tr>
       <tr><td>b</td></tr>
       <tr><td>c</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
  <button>another click</button>
```

Comment: not in the actual code in the sense?  so how your HTML is in actual code? we can only come up with the solution from the input which you have given. so please give a proper input so that we can help you.